# Custom Configuration Sections

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I am currently trying to implement a Custom Configuration Section in a project I am busy with and no matter what I try I keep getting the error below:

{"An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for pageAppearanceGroup/pageAppearance: Could not load type 'Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection' from assembly 'System.Configuration, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. (E:\Three Nine Developments\lastfm\msdn\msdn\bin\Debug\Samples.Aspnet.vshost.exe.config line 6)"}

I have copied the code from this MSDN Artricle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx

I still get the same error.

I have tried the all the advice/guide in the following articles but to no avail.
http://www.evanclosson.com/devlog/bettercustomerrorsinaspnetcustomconfigurationsection

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200810043157/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx)

This must be something stupid that I am missing.
I am running Vista, could that be a problem? some obscure security setting?

```
    <configuration>
  <!-- Configuration section-handler declaration area. -->
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
      <section
        name="pageAppearance"
        type="Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection"
        allowLocation="true"
        allowDefinition="Everywhere"
      />
    </sectionGroup>
    <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
  </configSections>

  <!-- Configuration section settings area. -->
  <pageAppearanceGroup>
    <pageAppearance remoteOnly="true">
      <font name="TimesNewRoman" size="18"/>
      <color background="000000" foreground="FFFFFF"/>
    </pageAppearance>
  </pageAppearanceGroup>



</configuration>
```

Comment: You will get more and better responses if you tag appropriately, i.e. with the technologies that you are using.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your web.config, can you post the relevant sections?

Comment: Nope Config is fine, I have truied App.config and web.config
I am able to read appSettings from the app.config and web.config jsut fine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also check out Jon Rista's three-part series on .NET 2.0 configuration up on CodeProject.

- [Unraveling the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx)
- [Decoding the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration2.aspx)
- [Cracking the mysteries of .NET 2.0 configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration3.aspx)

Highly recommended, well written and extremely helpful!

Marc

Comment: Thanks will definetly have a look at these

Comment: Give a man a fish and feed him for a day,
Show him how to fish and feed him for the rest of his life .
Thanks will be going through those articles carefully

Comment: I have read thos articles downloaded the projects they run no problem
When I try replicate the project they fail??
I have no idea why

Comment: Well, very often, it's just a matter of getting the assembly and class names 100% correct when you define the config section groups and config sections - that's caused the most trouble in my case.

Answer (score 19):

My guess is that you've copied the code, but you have different assembly names. Posting the config will help.

I would also fully quality your type in the config (something that sample doesn't show). Something like...

```
<section name="MySection" type="My.Assembly.Type, My.Assembly" />
```

Comment: Nope thats not right.
I have named the assemblies correctly.
Created different projects trying to do the same thing

Comment: OK. Seeing the config section definition will help.

Comment: Fully qualifying the Type did it for me.  Ensure that all your other bits are plumbed to :)

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following code:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
         <section name="pageAppearance" type="Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection,Samples.AspNet" allowLocation="true"         allowDefinition="Everywhere"       />
    </sectionGroup>     <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
</configSections>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this

```
<configSections>
 <sectionGroup name="pageAppearanceGroup">
  <section name="pageAppearance"
           type="Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection,Samples.AspNet"
           allowLocation="true"
           allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
 </sectionGroup>
 <!-- Other <section> and <sectionGroup> elements. -->
</configSections>
```

Thanks,
Vedi

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that when you create a project in Visual Studio, it automatically defines a **root namespace** (the name of the project by default) for the project. Thus you must include that root namespace in the section type as well as any custom namespaces you defined within your settings class.

For example, in the case of the original poster a working configuration for them may have looked something like this:

```
<section name="MySection" type="ROOT_NAMESPACE.Samples.AspNet.PageAppearanceSection, NAME_OF_ASSEMBLY" />
```

Where ROOT_NAMESPACE and NAME_OF_ASSEMBLY are defined in the project properties as shown in this snapshot of my project.

[image: assembly name and root namespace visual studio]

In my particular case, I did not explicitly define namespaces in my project. Thus my section configuration setting just had the root namespace, the name of the settings class, and the name of the assembly, as such;

```
<section name="programSettings" type="ShipmentImport.ProgramSettings, ShipmentImport" />
```

I know its a couple years late, but I hope it keeps somebody else from spending hours on this like I did.