# Multiple identical custom config sctions in app.config

Tags: .net, app-config, console-application, custom-sections

I'm attempting to create a custom config section in the app.config file of my C# .NET console application. It's to store some details about some servers, like so:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="serverGroup">
    <section name="server" type="RPInstaller.ServerConfig" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<serverGroup>
  <server>
    <name>rmso2srvm</name>
    <isBatchServer>false</isBatchServer>
  </server>
  <server>
    <name>rmsb2srvm</name>
    <isBatchServer>true</isBatchServer>
  </server>
</serverGroup>
```

I have a class defined for the server section like so:

```
namespace RPInstaller
{
    public class ServerConfig : ConfigurationSection
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired=true)]
        public string Name {...}

        [ConfigurationProperty("isBatchServer", IsRequired = true)]
        public bool IsBatchServer {...}
    }
}
```

When I now attempt to load the server sections I get an exception: "Sections must only appear once per config file".

How would I be able to legally define multiple server sections within my app.config file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<confgisections>
    <section name="server" type="RPInstaller.ServerConfig" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
</confgisections>
<server>
  <servers>
    </clear>
    <add name="rmso2srvm" isBatchServer="false"/>
    <add name="rmsb2srvm" isBatchServer="true"/>
  </servers>
</server>
```

Is how I have set up a custom section previously

VB Code to access:

```
 Dim cfg As ServerSection = (ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Server"),ServerSection)
 cfg.ServersCollection("nameOfServer").isBatchServer
```

Comment: The real answer is a mixture of this one and the one left by VMAtm. I found the links within the answer to the following question very helpful: [Custom Configuration Sections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858618/custom-configuration-sections)

Answer (score 0):

You can't create multiple server sections in the one web.config.
Only multiple elements in your custom sections.
Check your web.config - it seems that error is caused not because of your code.

---

Update:
You didn't define a element for your "server" element - only for ConfigurationSection.
So the runtime awaits section like

  rmso2srvm
  false

You should add the `ServerElement : ConfigurationElement` class, and add it to the definition of your section class:

```
namespace RPInstaller
{
  public class ServerConfig : ConfigurationSection 
  {
    public class ServerElement : ConfigurationElement
    {
        [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired=true)]
        public string Name {...}
        [ConfigurationProperty("isBatchServer", IsRequired = true)]
        public bool IsBatchServer {...}  
    }
  }
}
```

More information here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx